# SwiftUI AccentColor Between Targets

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible to share the accent color between targets?

```
Color.accentColor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccentColor` is kept in `Assets.xcassets` file by default. And you can decide its source name in `Project`>`Buid Settings`>`Global Accent Color Name`. So, you can create an `.xcassets` file, share between your targets and set your `AccentColor` in this file.